# show that $a_{n+874}=a_{n}$,if such $a_{n+2}=\left\lceil \frac{4}{3}a_{n+1}-a_{n}+0.5\right\rceil$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions

> Let the sequence  $\{a_{n}\}$ be such that $a_{1}=1, a_{2}=100$, and  $$a_{n+2}=\left\lceil \dfrac{4}{3}a_{n+1}-a_{n}+0.5\right\rceil$$
>
> Prove that the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is periodic.

I have used a computer and found the periodic is $T=874$, but how to prove it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then the period is in fact 2204, since $(a_{2205}, a_{2206}) = (1, 100)$ and no such pattern between 1 and 2205.

Comment: You are correct: $(a_1,\,a_2) = (1,\,100) = (a_{1+2204},\,a_{2+2204})$. Nevertheless, it seems that this case is not something exceptional. It is most likely that for every starting pair $(a_1,\,a_2)$, the resulting sequence is **periodic!** At least this is true for for all cases $\{-100 \le a_1,a_2 \le +100\}$. For example, corresponding to the question period, we have: $(a_1,\,a_2) = (1,\,99) = (a_{1+874},\,a_{2+874})$.

Comment: I'm confused. Didn't Sangchul already give a proof? You can compute $(a_{2205},a_{2206}) = (1,100)$, and then that tells you the sequence is periodic.

Comment: If two consecutive terms determine the next term, also if we have already observe 874 is a period, then we are done. Maybe an interesting question is whether we can remove brute force computation to find the same.

Comment: Could you reveal where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 13):

This is not an answer, but rather an observation.

---

The following graph shows the set of points $P = \{(a_n, a_{n+1}) : n \geq 1\}$.

$\hspace{8em}$[image]

Notice that they are confined in a very narrow region and are clustered near an ellipse. This ellipse is not hard to identify. Indeed, if a sequence $(b_n)$ satisfies

$$ b_{n+2} = \frac{4}{3}b_{n+1} - b_n, $$

then it follows that

$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} b_{n+1} & b_n \\ b_{n+2} & b_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} = b_{n+1}^2 - \frac{4}{3}b_{n+1}b_n + b_n^2 $$

is constant, since

$$ \begin{pmatrix} b_{n+2} & b_{n+1} \\ b_{n+3} & b_{n+2} \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & \frac{4}{3} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} b_{n+1} & b_n \\ b_{n+2} & b_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & \frac{4}{3} \end{pmatrix} = 1. $$

Thus the points $(b_n, b_{n+1})$ stays forever on the ellipse

$$f(x, y) := x^2 - \frac{4}{3}xy + y^2 = \text{const}.$$

If we can somehow show that $f(a_n, a_{n+1})$ is also bounded by some perturbation argument, then since the region $f(x, y) \leq c$ is bounded and $P$ has only integer points, we can argue that $(a_n)$ is eventually periodic. But at this point, I am not sure if this observation will be really useful.

Comment: Nice plot. Mind sharing the code you used ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, Unfortunately I neither saved nor remember the code exactly. But it was a Mathematica code that looked like this: `l = NestList[{#[[2]], Ceiling[4/3 #[[2]] - #[[1]] + 1/2]} &, {1, 100}, 2204];
Show[Graphics[Point /@ l]]`

Answer (score 0):

N.B. This is not complete answer, but just extrapolation of the clue provided by @SangchulLee.

---

First of all we can rewrite the recurrence as:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{4a_{n+1}}{3}-a_{n}+v_{n+1}$$
where
$$v_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
  1 & a_{n+1} = 0 \bmod 3\\
  \frac{2}{3} & a_{n+1} = 1 \bmod 3 \\
  \frac{4}{3} & a_{n+1} = 2 \bmod 3
\end{cases}$$

Now we define
$$A_{n}  =    \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\
  a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}
  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B  =  \begin{bmatrix}
    0&1  \\
    -1&\frac{4}{3}
    \end{bmatrix}$$
$$U_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0&0  \\
    0&1
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$$U_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0&0  \\
    1&0
    \end{bmatrix}$$
This means
$$A_{n+1}  =  BA_{n}+v_{n+1}U_1+v_{n+2}U_2$$
Then we can write
$$\det(A_{n+1}-v_{n+2}U_2) = \det(A_{n}+v_{n+1}B^{-1}U_1) $$

Simplifying this one obtains
$$a_{n+2}^2-\frac{4a_{n+2}a_{n+1}}{3}+a_{n+1}^2-v_{n+1}(a_{n+2}+a_{n+1})  =  a_{n+1}^2-\frac{4a_{n+1}a_n}{3}+a_n^2-v_{n+1}(a_{n+1}+a_n)$$

Notice that the equation $x^2-4xy/3+y^2-v(x+y)=C$ represents an ellipse for a given constant $C$ and $v\in\{1,2/3,4/3\}$

I was not able to proceed from here! Hope this helps although its a little late!